# Chrome Extension - Quota Exceeded Error (code 10) even for empty files

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, filesystems

I'm trying to save an empty file through HTML5 file system API on a Chrome extension.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(
    1024*1024,
    function(grantedBytes) {
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, successCallback, errorCallback);
        console.log(grantedBytes);
    },
    function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    }
);
customBarDocumentLoad();
booksDocumentLoad();
});
```

But the `console.log(grantedBytes);` returns a '0' to the console.

What am I missing and why does that happen?

Comment: Apparently it's deprecated, just use requestFileSystem directly and handle the quota error. Or maybe it's a bug worth submitting to https://crbug.com